# Do I have to attribute Apache font license when using it for e-book and print book?

Tags: copyright, licensing, publishing, digital-contract

I'm currently in the process of writing a book, and I'm using mostly OFL fonts in it, but I also find some Apache licensed fonts very attractive and would like to use them.

The condition for using Apache licensed fonts in code is to attribute it in the code but in my case, should I attribute them in my e-book and print book (which will be a commercial use product)? Also if yes then how can I make it so that the license becomes less disruptive to the book reading experience itself?

P.S. The question has been reposted here on recommendation of a user from writing.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109605/can-i-use-an-ofl-or-apache-font-to-produce-a-commercial-product-based-around-the

Comment: Both of them do not mention attribution which is required when the font is getting redistributed in the derivative works, especially in case of ebook where the font could get embedded (.pdf files for example). Refer to section 4 of the Apache v2 license.